# How to know the netwrok traffic my test (using JMeter) is going to generate?

Tags: networking, jmeter, traffic

I am going to run load test using JMeter over Amazon AWS and I need to know before starting my test how much traffic is it going to generate over network.
The criteria that Amazon has in their policy is:
sustains, in aggregate, for more than 1 minute, over 1 Gbps (1 billion bits per second) or 1 Gpps (1 billion packets per second). If my test is going to exceed this criteria we need to submit a form before starting the test.
so how can I know if the test is going to exceed this number or not?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run your test with 1 virtual user and 1 iteration in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

   ```
    jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```
2. To get an approximate figure open Open the `result.csv` file using [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener and there you will have 2 columns: `Received KB/sec` and `Sent KB/sec`. Multiply it by the duration of your test in seconds and you will get the number you're looking for.
   [image]

   alternatively you can open the `result.csv` file using [MS Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en/microsoft-365/excel) or [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or equivalent where you can sum `bytes` and `sentBytes` columns and get the traffic with 1 byte precision:

   [image]